# Can't compile project in c++, regardless of IDEs

Tags: 20.04, compiling, eclipse, c++, cmake

I have been having problems with running c++ programs on ubuntu 20.04. The problem is, that even I write legit code that the compiler can understand, the same error occurs saying that "Error: build command 'cmake' not foundFailure running cmake: " I have tried Eclipse and Visual Studio code. I haven't encountered this problem on windows however.Can someone help with that.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `cmake`, install it by running this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

Comment: i did and it solved. However i have another problem. "Error: could not load cache" How can I solve that